# Is it possible to do inner join with ON and IN constraints?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

`post` and `tags` have ManyToMany relationship.
In typeorm, this is perfectry valid:

```
  await this.postsRepo.find({
    take: limit,
    skip: limit * pageNumber,
    join: {
        alias: 'post',
        innerJoinAndSelect: {
            tags: 'post.tags',
        },
    },
});
```

While I want to also be able to filter `post.tag` by ids, something like this:

```
await this.postsRepo.find({
    take: limit,
    skip: limit * pageNumber,
    join: {
        alias: 'post',
        innerJoinAndSelect: {
            tags: {
                alias: 'post.tags',
                on: {
                    'post.tags': In([validTagIds])
                }
            }
        },
    },
```

});

But I do not want to use the `selectQueryBuilder`. Is it possible by using the `.find` function?